# How do i add 0 in database for telephone number

Tags: mysql, sql

so i want to put 0 in my telephone columndatabase
i have tried using this code but it keeps getting error said unexpected "0" and for that column i am using int

```
  mysqli_query($koneksi,"INSERT INTO distributor VALUES('','$nama_distributor','$alamat','"0".$telpon')");
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: yeah i havent add the code to prevent sql injection because this is just  a final project for my school

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `concat()` function

```
mysqli_query($koneksi,"INSERT INTO distributor 
 VALUES('','$nama_distributor','$alamat',concat('0','$telpon'))");
```

Comment: still didnt work,my telephone column use int by the way

Comment: @IanIndratama int has no leading zeros. Also a phone number is not always a number.

Comment: @Jens so what should i do ? should i change it to varchar ?

Comment: @IanIndratama yes

Answer (score 0):

You have to mentions the column names like this and use the `cast()` function

```
Declare @Num1 int
set @Num1 = 0

 mysqli_query($koneksi,"INSERT INTO distributor (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES('','$nama_distributor','$alamat', cast(@Num1 as varchar() + $telephone as varchar(12)");
```

Comment: If you're not able to use `concat()` function, try this